# Sorting a Python list by third element, then by first element, etc?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Say I have a list in the form [[x,y,z], [x,y,z] etc...] etc where each grouping represents a random point.

I want to order my points by the z coordinate, then within each grouping of z's, sort them by x coordinate. Is this possible?

Comment: Moving goal posts John Smith. Your question is a well written question, up until you commented in Andrew White's answer that your datastructure isn't as described in your question. This is rather poor form.

Comment: @JohnSmith It will be helpful if you edit your question by including original datastructre which you have mentioned in comments below. At first glance I almost missed your comment there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, look at [this page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) under the section called "Operator Module Functions." Basically you just need to use sort's key feature with the itemgetter operator...

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(tuples, key=itemgetter(2,0))
```

Comment: That looks great -- unfortunately I forgot to leave out an important detail.

My points are actually in the form [ [[x,y,z],[x1,y1,z1]] , [[x,y,z],[x1,y1,z1]] ... ] etc

Is there a way to have it sort by the x y z (not looking at the x1 y1 z1 stuff?

Comment: @JohnSmith - in this case replace @AndrewWhite's `itemgetter(2,0)` with `lambda x: (x[0][2], x[0][0])` and you can ignore the `import operator …` too.

Comment: Perfect; thanks so much, everyone. Apologies again for moving the goalposts.

Comment: @eumiro Could you please post your comment as an answer otherwise it can be missed easily?

Answer (score 2):

For simple lookup, use `itemgetter` as suggested by [Andrew White](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522862/577088). But for more complex lookups, you may have to create a function, either with `def` or with `lambda`. For example:

```
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0][2], x[0][0]))
[[[10, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[8, 13, 9], [15, 16, 17]], [[9, 3, 9], [9, 10, 11]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your list is in the form

```
[ [[x,y,z],[x1,y1,z1]] , [[x,y,z],[x1,y1,z1]] ... ]
```

then use this:

```
sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: (x[0][2], x[0][0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go further down the page Mr. White linked to, you'll see how you can specify an arbitrary function to compute your sort key (using the handy cmp_to_key function provided).